# Mock a local variable in an MVC action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, nunit, moq

Using Moq or Rhino, I'd like to mock a local variable in one of my MVC action methods.

In my program I have a 'ProfileController' for instance, with a method that looks like:

```
        public ActionResult Profile(ProfileOptions oProfile)
        {
            ProfileViewModel oModel = new ProfileViewModel(); // <--can I mock this?

            //… do work, using oModel along the way

            return View(oModel);

         }
```

My tests would create a new ProfileController in the test class' `[SetUp]` method, and I'd run various tests on its action methods using it.

I'd like to mock the `oModel` variable above when calling the `Profile` method in my tests, but as it's local and not being passed in via injection can I somehow do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to mock the object, you could use a construction method/type that is declared and instantiated at class level, then mock that type.

```
public class MyController
{
    // If you're using DI, you should use constructor injection instead of this:
    protected IProfileViewModelBuilder _builder = new ProfileViewModelBuilder();

    ...
    public ActionResult Profile(ProfileOptions oProfile)
    {
        ProfileViewModel oModel = _builder.Build(); // <--I CAN mock this!

        //… do work, using oModel along the way

        return View(oModel);

     }
    ...

}
```

One benefit to this approach is that if in the future the creation of your ViewModel becomes more complicated, any changes required are isolated to a single location.

Hope that helps,

Mike